# Deserialize JSON objects in differents formats to a common class

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have results from several different HTTP APIs containing currency rates.
Results are very similar, but unfortunately they are not exactly the same.

I'd like to deserialize them to an object with a fixed common type for all of them.
I suppose there's some better way than to do manual string tampering.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Let's say:

-in result from `API1` I get:

```
field_1, field_2, field_3
```

-in result from `API2` I get:

```
field_1, field_2, field_007,
```

-in result from `API3` I get:

```
field_111, field_2, field_3,
```

And the class to which I'd like to deserialize the results looks like this:

```
class DeserializedJson
{
    public string field_1 { get; set; }
    public string field_2 { get; set; }
    public string field_3 { get; set; }
}
```

What's important in this example: `field_3` from `DeserializedJson` object can appear only as `field_3` or `field_007`. These two options.

So I just wonder whether is there a conditional deserialization attribute or something like this?

Comment: How do you determine which "field_xxx" value from the JSON maps to which field in your class?

Comment: @BrianRogers Please look at my update. field_xxx can appear in strictly specified forms.

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: @Grx70 I have no serializer. These data come from external HTTP APIs

Comment: What I meant was which serializer are you using do deserialize the data?

Comment: @Grx70 I have no solution yet. I'm gathering opinions if is it possible

Comment: After short investigation it seems to be possible. If you're going to use `Json.NET`, you could implement custom `IContractResolver`. If you're going to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`, you could implement custom `IDataContractSurrogate`. In my opinion though the simplest solution is to create different class for each contract, all implementing common interface.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>**Note:** This answer was written assuming you will be using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json).  After I posted, I realized that you never specifically mentioned in your question what serializer you were using (or wanted to use).  I think you could still use the same technique presented here with other serializers, but you may have to make adjustments. YMMV.</sub>

Well, as long as your mappings don't overlap, then one simple solution is to have private setters in your class for Json.Net to use which will set the correct public property.  This works because Json.Net will ignore class members that are not in the JSON.  Here is what the modified class would look like if you took that approach:

```
class DeserializedJson
{
    public string field_1 { get; set; }
    public string field_2 { get; set; }
    public string field_3 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    private string field_007 
    {
        set { field_3 = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty]
    private string field_111 
    {
        set { field_1 = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is a demo to prove that this works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeserializeAndDump(1, @"{""field_1"":""a"",""field_2"":""b"",""field_3"":""c""}");
        DeserializeAndDump(2, @"{""field_1"":""d"",""field_2"":""e"",""field_007"":""f""}");
        DeserializeAndDump(3, @"{""field_111"":""g"",""field_2"":""h"",""field_3"":""i""}");
    }

    private static void DeserializeAndDump(int n, string json)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--- API " + n + " ---");
        DeserializedJson obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedJson>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("field_1: " + obj.field_1);
        Console.WriteLine("field_2: " + obj.field_2);
        Console.WriteLine("field_3: " + obj.field_3);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- API 1 ---
field_1: a
field_2: b
field_3: c

--- API 2 ---
field_1: d
field_2: e
field_3: f

--- API 3 ---
field_1: g
field_2: h
field_3: i
```

Of course, this approach will not work if, for example, `field_007` in the JSON sometimes maps to `field_3` and sometimes maps to `field_2` in your class.  If that is the case, then you would need to create a separate "DeserializedJson" class for each different API method.  You could make them all inherit from the same base class and use the above technique in each subclass to set the correct properties in the base class.  Here's what that would look like:

```
class DeserializedJson
{
    public string field_1 { get; set; }
    public string field_2 { get; set; }
    public string field_3 { get; set; }
}

class DeserializedJsonAPI1 : DeserializedJson
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string field_007
    {
        set { field_2 = value; }
    }
}

class DeserializedJsonAPI2 : DeserializedJson
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string field_007
    {
        set { field_3 = value; }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeserializeAndDump<DeserializedJsonAPI1>(1, @"{""field_1"":""q"",""field_007"":""r"",""field_3"":""s""}");
        DeserializeAndDump<DeserializedJsonAPI2>(2, @"{""field_1"":""x"",""field_2"":""y"",""field_007"":""z""}");
    }

    private static void DeserializeAndDump<T>(int n, string json) where T : DeserializedJson
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--- API " + n + " ---");
        DeserializedJson obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("field_1: " + obj.field_1);
        Console.WriteLine("field_2: " + obj.field_2);
        Console.WriteLine("field_3: " + obj.field_3);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- API 1 ---
field_1: q
field_2: r
field_3: s

--- API 2 ---
field_1: x
field_2: y
field_3: z
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
(YourClass)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeof(YourClass));
```

Unless I have misunderstood. If you want a "common" type use inheritance.

Comment: Maybe something along these lines?

`public static dynamic Convert(dynamic source, Type dest) {
  return Convert.ChangeType(source, dest);
}`